# NSDateFormatter Bug : incorrect string to date conversion

Tags: objective-c, nsdateformatter, utc

I have an a string in UTC which i want to convert to NSDate. Somehow Im getting 30 minutes error

The string is 
**2012-04-10T00:00:00+05:30**

the converted date is 
**2012-04-09 19:00:00 +0000**

where as it should have been
**2012-04-09 18:30:00 +0000**

Im using this function to convert string to date

```
- (NSDate *)parseRFC3339Date{
    NSDateFormatter *rfc3339TimestampFormatterWithTimeZone = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [rfc3339TimestampFormatterWithTimeZone setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];

    NSDate *theDate = nil;
    NSError *error = nil; 
    if (![rfc3339TimestampFormatterWithTimeZone getObjectValue:&theDate forString:self range:nil error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Date '%@' could not be parsed: %@", self, error);
    }

    [rfc3339TimestampFormatterWithTimeZone release];
    return theDate;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into **ISOdateFormatter** here http://boredzo.org/iso8601unparser/ which works perfectly. Fund it better than modifying incoming date strings.

Answer (score 2):

If you were to create an `NSRange` covering the whole of the string and passed its address in to `-getObjectValue:forString:range:error:`, then you'd see that on output it would be short.  Parsing stopped at the colon because the 'Z' in the format string only matches something like "-0800" (no colon).  If you were to specify 4 Zs, 'ZZZZ', it would match something like "GMT-08:00".  That allows a colon, but requires "GMT".  You can try inserting the "GMT" if you're sure of the format of your date string.